# Insight on term query performance and index structuring in general

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently started to use Elastic Search for the first time and i'm looking for some insight/help. I have a problem with a term query that does not perform very well and that lead me to believe that my approach of "partitioning" the indices might not be the best. I hope someone can give some insight into this.

the dataset i need to move into Elastic Search consists of approx. 60-70 million records. the records are basically person+address+metadata records and there are two obvious ways to partition/split them into several indices. the way i do it right now is by creating 4 indices. these 4 indices are associated with the 4 different "types" of records that are contained in the dataset. think of the 4 types as "customer accounts", "prospects", "debtors" and "black listed persons/addresses". each of the records in these 4 indices is associated with a company and i want to be able to search (among other things) by "type" and by "company".

"by type" is easy, i just address the index that is assoiated with the type. for the "by company" part i started using a term query like this one (it's a bool query because it usually includes additional search parameters that i excluded here for simplicity/clarity):

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [{
          "term": { "company":  "MY COMPANY NAME" }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

it turns out that this query is not very fast, at least not for the "customer account" index and the largest company that has aprox. 16 million customer account records.

my understanding is that in the inverse index there will be an entry for "MY COMPANY NAME" that will have 16 million documents associated with it, and the term query has to iterate over all of them.

profiling the query reveals that most of the time is spent on "next_doc" (which is the iterating part as far as i understand):

```
"profile": {"shards": [   {
  "id": "[ysJiBZNTRsuha0E8LU28sA][kunden][0]",
  "searches": [      {
     "query": [         {
        "type": "BoostQuery",
        "description": "(ConstantScore(company:MY COMPANY NAME))^0.0",
        "time_in_nanos": 11295720987,
        "breakdown":             {
           "score": 2778410326,
           "build_scorer_count": 54,
           "match_count": 0,
           "create_weight": 19602,
           "next_doc": 8485047975,
           "match": 0,
           "create_weight_count": 1,
           "next_doc_count": 15728947,
           "score_count": 15728921,
           "build_scorer": 785161,
           "advance": 0,
           "advance_count": 0
        },
        "children": [            {
           "type": "TermQuery",
           "description": "company:MY COMPANY NAME",
           "time_in_nanos": 2873750226,
           "breakdown":                {
              "score": 0,
              "build_scorer_count": 54,
              "match_count": 0,
              "create_weight": 9745,
              "next_doc": 2857426300,
              "match": 0,
              "create_weight_count": 1,
              "next_doc_count": 15728947,
              "score_count": 0,
              "build_scorer": 585179,
              "advance": 0,
              "advance_count": 0
           }
        }]
     }],
```

by the way, the company field is mapped as a "keyword" field.

at this point i'm unsure how to tackle this performance problem.

Is there maybe another query type that can do this more efficient? or can i parameterize the term query differently to make it faster?

I also considered to put each combination of "type" and "company" into it's own index to avoid the term query "by company" alltogether.

so i would have for example an index named "prospects_COMPANY_A", another named "prospects_COMPANY_B", another named "debtors_COMPANY_A" and so forth.

so i could filter by "type" and by "company" by adressing the proper index and then just filter by the additional search parameters that i excluded in my example here (that part of the query (a bunch of "should"-clauses) is already very fast)

but i'm not sure if that is a good idea either, because it would result in a lot of indices (there are aprox. 60 different companies in the dataset), many of them would hold only a couple of thousand or maybe tens of thousand records. and for queries that search "all companies" i would potentially have to search in 60 indices in parallel. which seems to have potential for a whole different can of worms.

I would love to get some input/insight about how to approach this.

Thanks in advance!

regards
Mario